# Is it safe to postulate unit types are equal?

Tags: haskell, types

Is it safe to postulate that all types of kind `()` are the same? That is, can the following be used to break type safety?

```
-- Bad postulate
unitsEqual :: (x :: ()) :~: (y :: ())
unitsEqual = unsafeCoerce (Refl :: '() :~: '())
```

Answer (score 5):

This is unsafe under GHC 7.8.3 (see code below). As user2407038 remarks, the following is rejected by GHC 7.10.3. Unsurprisingly, this data family is evil enough that the type checker was changed to prohibit it. I'm still trying to see if there's a way to make this happen under 7.10.3.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

module UnitsEqual where
import Unsafe.Coerce
import Data.Type.Equality

data family Yeah (a :: ()) b c
data instance Yeah '() b c = Yeah { yeah :: b }
data instance Yeah a b c = Nope c

-- Entirely valid
castYeah :: x :~: y -> Yeah x p q -> Yeah y p q
castYeah Refl x = x

-- Bad postulate
unitsEqual :: (x :: ()) :~: (y :: ())
unitsEqual = unsafeCoerce (Refl :: '() :~: '())

-- Oh no! This doesn't actually cast, but
-- it's horrible enough. It consistently produces
-- either segmentation faults or nonsense,
-- whether the types are the same or not.
uc :: a -> b
uc a = yeah $ castYeah unitsEqual (Nope a)
```

<strike>I *believe*, however, that it *is* safe to postulate</strike>

```
voidsEqual :: (a :: Void) :~: (b :: Void)
```

because there's no apparent way to distinguish any of the stuck/bogus types inhabiting `Void`.

Comment: This gives "Conflicting family instance declarations" for `Yeah` on GHC 7.10.3.

Comment: @user2407038, interesting! I tested it under 7.8.3. I shall have to see whether I can patch this up to work on 7.10.3.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this answer is mainly guesswork, because this behaviour really confused me and I still am not too sure of exactly the semantics of `Any` in the typechecker.

In your example, disregarding that `Yeah` should probably be rejected, when it computes the type of `Nope a` it finds an ambiguous type variable and instantiates it to `Any`. This is the same mechanism that makes e.g. `length []` work.

You can do the same with a GADT, which is accepted on GHC 7.10:

```
data Yeah (a :: ()) b c where 
  Yeah :: b -> Yeah '() b c 
  Nope :: c -> Yeah Any b c
```

To write `uc` you need a function

```
yeah :: Yeah '() b c -> b 
yeah (Yeah a) = a 
yeah (Nope _) = error "???"
```

In the second case, the equality `'() ~ Any` is given, which I assumed was trivially false, as are e.g. `'True ~ 'False`, `Int ~ Bool`, etc. The typechecker knows these facts:

```
okay :: 'True :~: 'False -> x
-- okay Refl = error "???" -- Compiler rejects this case
okay x = case x of
```

but not this one!

```
really :: Any :~: '() -> x
really Refl = error "???" -- Perfectly valid pattern match
```

You can't actually call this function:

```
>:t really Refl

<interactive>:1:8: Warning:
    Couldn't match type `Any' with '()
    Expected type: Any :~: '()
      Actual type: '() :~: '()
    In the first argument of `really', namely `Refl'
    In the expression: really Refl
```

and while `uc` typechecks (definition unchanged) it no longer breaks:

```
>uc 'a' :: Int
*** Exception: ???
```

It would seem that the typechecker does not believe that `'() :~: Any` is uninhabited, because it isn't, because the typechecker is internally allowed to produce such a proof, but the user is still barred from writing it themselves.

All this to say: I think if you pretend `Any` does not exist, then `unitsEqual` is sound, and the unsoundness arises from the existence of `Any`. It would seem to be explicitly false by counterexample - `Any :~: '()` - but it seems there is a special typechecker rule for `Any` that says `x ~ y` is trivially false only if `x` and `y` are different types and neither `x` or `y` is `Any`.

`voidEqual` is equally unsound because `Any :: Void`, `Any Any :: Void`, `Any Any Any :: Void`, etc.

Comment: `Any` is not a special case (any more). It's now defined as `type family Any :: k where {}`. It's a "stuck type family".

Comment: I assume that is of GHC 8.0 or the like? It doesn't seem to even be valid syntax with 7.10.3.

Comment: I guess so. You can get all the same features with an open type family if you just never make any instances.